# CGRect image resizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm using CGRect to display an image. I'd like the CGRect to use the width and height of the image without me specifying it.

can this:

```
CGRectMake(0.0f, 40.0f, 480.0f, 280.0f);
```

become this:

```
CGRectMake(0.0f, 40.0f, myImage.width, myImage.height);
```

some images get distorted when I specify the parameters.

here's the code:

```
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 40.0f, 480.0f, 280.0f);
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:recipe.img]];
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you have a `UIImage`, you can find its size by looking at the [size](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624105-size?language=objc) property:

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:recipe.img];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 40.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);

UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[imageView setImage:image];
```

Comment: that worked great. thanks

if I wanted to center the rect would you do that w/ the '0.0f, 40.0f' points or is there a better way since the images are different sizes?

Comment: You could default them to 0,0 then set the image view's center property: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/center Might be worthwhile skimming the documentation for UIImage, UIImageView and UIView because there are probably other things there which will be useful for you. Reading the list of available methods and properties at the top would be a good start, so would reading the introduction sections of those three pages, just to get an idea of what Apple puts where.

Answer (score 3):

This category on UIImage might be helpful.

Use it like this: `aImage =[aImage imageByScalingProportionallyToSize: myImageRect]`

```
@implementation UIImage (Extras)

- (UIImage *)imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:(CGSize)targetSize {

    UIImage *sourceImage = self;
    UIImage *newImage = nil;

    CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
    CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
    CGFloat height = imageSize.height;

    CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
    CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;

    CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
    CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
    CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;

    CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO) {

        CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
        CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

        if (widthFactor < heightFactor) 
            scaleFactor = widthFactor;
        else
            scaleFactor = heightFactor;

        scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
        scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

        // center the image

//        if (widthFactor < heightFactor) {
//          thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5; 
//        } else if (widthFactor > heightFactor) {
//          thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
//        }

        //thumbnailPoint.x
    }


    // this is actually the interesting part:

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);

    CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
    thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
    thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
    thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

    [sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if(newImage == nil) NSLog(@"could not scale image");


    return newImage ;
}

@end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Since I hadn't dealt with modifying Objective-C classes before, these proved useful: [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Categories)